# Populating temporary table with result of independent Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to return a temporary table from `stored procedure` which populates with data retrieved from two independent sql query

```
Select column1,column2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE someCondition
Select column3,column4 FROM TABLE1 WHERE someOtherCondition
INSERT INTO Temp_table(column1,column2,column3,column4) values VALUE from those two table
```

Some of the result from table contains null as well.Also i am using some mathematical function like `sum` on some column as well
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out with following code:

```
INSERT INTO Temp_table (column1, column2, column3, column4)
SELECT column1, column2, ISNULL(column3,0), ISNULL(column4,0) FROM TABLE1 WHERE someCondition
UNION ALL
SELECT ISNULL(column1,0), ISNULL(column2,0), column3, column4 FROM TABLE1 WHERE someOtherCondition
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO Temp_table (column1, column2, column3, column4)
SELECT column1, column2, NULL AS column3, NULL AS column4 FROM TABLE1 WHERE someCondition
UNION
SELECT NULL AS column1, NULL AS column2, column3, column4 FROM TABLE1 WHERE someOtherCondition
```